# Trying to Deploy Django App Through Elastic Beanstalk, Module not found error

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy a Django application AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

I followed this guide:
https://medium.com/@justaboutcloud/how-to-deploy-a-django3-application-on-elastic-beanstalk-python3-7-and-amazon-linux-2-bd9b8447b55
but when I attempt to deploy I have a 502 error when I go to the site page, and when I look through the logs the error I have is ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django3.wsgi'

My code is stored like this:

```
django3 
 |--- manage.py
 |--- requirements.txt
 |--- .ebextensions
       |--- 01_python.config
 |--- django3
       |--- __init__.py
       |--- asgi.py
       |--- settings.py
       |--- urls.py
       |--- wsgi.py
```

And my 01_python.config file has:

```
option_settings:
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment":
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: "django3.settings"
    "PYTHONPATH": "/var/app/current:$PYTHONPATH"
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python":
    WSGIPath: django3.wsgi:application
    NumProcesses: 3
    NumThreads: 20
```

My requirements.txt file is

```
asgiref==3.4.1
Django==3.2.5
gunicorn==20.1.0
pytz==2021.1
sqlparse==0.4.1
```

I'm not sure what I have that is wrong, if someone could help me out that would be great. I've tried messing around with the formatting of the 01_python.config file but nothing is helping fix the issue.

Comment: Which platform are you using...? As per the note in [official document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html) `If you're using an Amazon Linux AMI Python platform version (preceding Amazon Linux 2), replace the value for WSGIPath with ebdjango/wsgi.py`

Comment: I'm not exactly sure on the platform, I'm using the Atom editor and the eb commands (as the guide explained), so I think it's windows.  My eb version is EB CLI 3.20.0 (Python 3.9.2) if that helps. I tried your version (for my code it would be django3/wsgi.py) but then I still get an error, ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django3/wsgi'

Comment: What happens if you change `WSGIPath: django3.wsgi:application` to `WSGIPath: django3.django3.wsgi:application`?

Comment: check 1.) pythonpath 2.) from which directly have you created zip

Comment: Jarad's comment did the trick for me, seems like I just wasn't encapsulating the entire directory and adding another django3. for the initial folder made it work.